# problem in fedora 14 update

Tags: linux, fedora, updates, yum

i try run this yum update command 
but i got this error ,

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
google                                                   | 1.5 kB     00:00     
http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for google: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: google. Please verify its path and try again
```

how to i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file looks fine here. You can try purging only that repo's data by using

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=google clean all
```

and then try again. If that still doesn't work then you can use `--disablerepo=google` to disable just that single repo until things are back to normal.